# constructing reference call with for_each in line

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

Whats going on?

- I have created a couple of  "google_compute_health_check" on GCP
- To re-use the health checks, my variables refer to whatever health_check they need
- I am now creating another resource that needs to refer to this health check

health-check.tf

```
resource "google_compute_health_check" "tcp-8008-hc" {
  name = "tcp-8008-hc"

  timeout_sec        = 5
  check_interval_sec = 5

  http_health_check {
    port         = "8008"
    request_path = "/"
  }
}

resource "google_compute_health_check" "tcp-80-hc" {
  name = "tcp-80-hc"

  timeout_sec        = 5
  check_interval_sec = 5

  http_health_check {
    port         = "80"
    request_path = "/"
  }
}
```

variables.tf

```
variable "applications" {
  default = {
    "app1" = {
      //.....(snipped)...
      health_check = "tcp-8008-hc"
      //.....(snipped)...
    },
    "app2" = {
      //.....(snipped)...
      health_check = "tcp-80-hc"
      //.....(snipped)...
    },
    "app3" = {
      //.....(snipped)...
      health_check = "tcp-8008-hc"
      //.....(snipped)...
    },
  }
}
```

**main.tf**

In this main.tf, I am creating another resource which needs to refer to the health-check based on the value of "health_check" variable of the current loop. I am not sure how do I do that with "each"?

```
resource "google_compute_backend_service" "backend" {
  //.....(snipped)...
  for_each = var.applications
  health_checks = [google_compute_health_check.each.value["health_check"].id]

}
```

Comment: Did this code output any errors?

Comment: Ah now I see where the issue is. You could try with: `google_compute_health_check[each.value.health_check].id`.

Comment: @MarkoE thats the problem. You can't use that because the plain text is expecting it to be "google_compute_health_check.RESOURCE_NAME.id"

Comment: Ah, yes, my bad. In that case, you would have to recreate all the health checks to have the same resource name and `for_each` would work. You can't get the resource name dynamically the way you want I think.

Comment: @MarkoE yep, you're right. I created a map and looped over it to create all health checks. Now all of them have the same "terraform resource name" convention of resource_compute_health_check.hc["whatever"].id